# OS-login granular access

Tags: google-cloud-platform, amazon-iam, gcloud

When using os-login is it possible to grant granular access to a particular server?

From the documentation it seems that once you give the roles roles/compute.osLogin or roles/compute.osAdminLogin you get access to everything in the project that has metadata tag for enable-oslogin=true.

I tried setting conditions on the role I am granting to set type name=instance-1 but this doesnt seem to work the way I am expecting.

Are my assumptions correct about not being able to grant granular access at a resource level?

Answer (score 0):

You can grant users permissions to specific Instances by granting Users access at the **Instance** rather than the **Project** (== all Project's Instances) level. E.g:

```sh
gcloud compute instances add-iam-policy-binding ${INSTANCE} \
--member=${MEMBER} \
--role=${ROLE} \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

If you grant a User permission at the Project level, the permission is inherited by Instances in the Project. E.g:

```sh
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
--member=${MEMBER} \
--role=${ROLE}
```

You can add OS Login metadata at the Organization, Project and Instance level. If you enable e.g. at the Project level, OS Login is inherited by Instances in the Project.